Qt 6.8 linux (gcc) webengine is missed
I noticed that in the Qt installer for Linux (GCC) in Qt 6.8, WebEngine has disappeared, but I couldn't find any official information about the reasons for its removal. Moreover, the official documentation continues to claim that it is available on the Linux platform, but in fact, it is not. Can someone help find answers about what happened and why it was removed?

Starting with Qt 6.8.0, the WebEngine has been hidden under Extensions and is not part of Qt folder anymore. Whoever thought that this is a good idea.

